# Displaying JSON in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, json, object, charts, chart.js

I'm fetching and parsing JSON data from a local file and I'm using [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) to display the data. The data I want to be displayed is the number of times a given word is used and the word as the chart label.

**Issues:**

I've managed to get the word and occurrence pair within the `wordCount` function. If I log out `counts`, I can see the match. 
What I'm having a pain point with is how to properly display the data with what I have so far. I'm seeing some of it displayed, but it isn't correct.

**Code:**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const tweets = []
const counts = {}
const keyz = []

// Fetch JSON file locally and return the data
fetch('../test_feed.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    handleTweetText(data)
    compare()
    wordCount()
    createChart()
  })
.catch(err => console.error(err));

function handleTweetText(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.content.length; i++) {
    const tweetHtml = data.content[i].content.bodyHtml;

    // If tweet exists, return it
    if(tweetHtml && tweetHtml != '') {
      // Regex to grab entire anchor tag
      const regEx = /<a(\s[^>]*)?>.*?<\/a>/ig
      // Replace anchor with empty string and remove empty space
      const splitTweetText = tweetHtml.replace(regEx, '').trim()
      tweets.push(splitTweetText)
    }
  }
}

function wordCount() {
  const allWords = tweets.join('\n')
  const tokens = allWords.split(/\W+/)

  for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    var word = tokens[i].toLowerCase()

    if (counts[word] === undefined) {
      counts[word] = 1 
      keyz.push(word)
    } else {
      counts[word] = counts[word] + 1
    }
  }  

}

// sort word occurrence 
keyz.sort(compare)

function compare(a ,b,) {
  const countA = counts[a]
  const countB = counts[b]
  return countB - countA
}

// Chart
function createChart() {
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
      labels: keyz,
      datasets: [{
          label: 'Word Count',
          data: keyz,
          backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 1
      }]
  }
})}
```

The `labels` fiels and `data` field within the `datasets` are where I need to place my paired data.

I've been working at this for awhile now with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

for one, `fetch` is asynchronous, so you have to wait for it to finish.
which is why you have `then` methods.

however, you're trying to sort `keyz` before `keyz` has any data.

move the sort function into the `then` method,
after `wordCount` where `keyz` is filled.
and calling `compare` on its own, does nothing...

```
// Fetch JSON file locally and return the data
fetch('../test_feed.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    handleTweetText(data)
    wordCount()
    keyz.sort(compare)
    createChart()
  })
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

but typically, you don't use the same data for both `labels` and `data` in the chart.
is it possible you meant to use `counts` for `data` in the chart?